# How to convert a group of TextView to EditText in android without ViewSwitcher?

Tags: android

ViewSwitcher can be used only for two childs in it. But for a group of textviews to be converted to Edittexts what can be the ways?

Comment: you can create a method and call it in a loop! why not?

Comment: Make two view group, one with TextViews and another with EditText. Use them as child of your ViewSwitcher.

Comment: Please upvote my answer too if it solved your issue :)

Comment: Thanx for your answer and sure i'll upvote you @Subby

Comment: @PradeepkumarGuruswamy I added more details to hopefully give you a bigger insight to the solution and why it's a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy enough to *replace* views for other views but *converting* - I don't think so.

To replace views, you can simply do something like the following:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_texts_layout, null);

viewSwitcher.removeAllViews();
viewSwitcher.addView(view.findViewById(R.id.first_edit_text));
viewSwitcher.addView(view.findViewById(R.id.second_edit_text));
```

**So what's going on here?**

1) You create a layout called *edit_texts_layout* which contains two `EditText`'s with the ID's: `first_edit_text` and `second_edit_text`.

2) You then inflate this in your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

3) You then remove all of the existing views in your `ViewSwitcher` since, as you rightfully said, there can only ever be two views in a `ViewSwitcher`.

4) You then add the two `EditText`'s inside that `ViewSwitcher` by `view.findViewById()`

**Also...**

It would be wise to have another layout called `text_views_layout` and do the exact same thing so that you can switch the `EditText`'s with the `TextView`'s.

**But why have the EditText's inside a layout and not create them programmatically?**

Good question. Views should live in layouts and live separately from code *when possible*. It makes life easy where you can work with a view in a layout since you have XML autocomplete and the preview screen so you know exactly what the view looks like - saving you from any nasty surprises later on.

**Are there any other alternatives to this?**

There's always more than one way to skin a cat and this situation is no different. You could possibly create TWO `ViewSwitcher`'s and with different child views. What you'd have to do then is toggle the visibility to `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE` alternatively. The caveat? It'll be troublesome to maintain both in memory and to perform any operations on the child views as you'd have to remember which one is visible and which one isn't. With my original answer, you won't have to worry.